# Getting Error trying to plot a folium map in PyQt5 GUI "Js: Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined". Proxy issue?

Tags: javascript, python, proxy, pyqt5, folium

I am writing a GUI app with PyQt5 that allows the user to plot a folium map and export polygons drawn. The code works well on a machine without a proxy server, but not on a machine that has to use a proxy. It reports the error: "Js: Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined". Here is the function I use to plot the map:

```
def display_map(self):
    global City
    global Country
    global LatLon
    City = self.lineEdit_city.text()
    Country = self.lineEdit_country.text()
    if City and Country:

        LatLon = ox.geocode(f'{City}, {Country}')
        map_4 = folium.Map(location = LatLon, tiles=None, zoom_start=15, maxZoom = 25, scroll_wheel_zoom = True, control_scale = True)
        folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(tiles='cartodbpositron').add_to(map_4)
        
        Draw(
            export=True,
            filename='Area_of_interest.geojson',
            position='topleft',
            draw_options={'polyline': False, 'circle': False, 'rectangle': False, 'circlemarker': False},
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}},
        ).add_to(map_4)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        map_4.save(data, close_file=False)
        
        self.view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
    else:
        self.popup_message(self.stack1, 'Fill in all Fields!')
```

The error above for the machine with the proxy could be overcome by implementing locally default_css and js. Another attempt has been done with the default.js for the draw plugin without success. Then, QWebengineview shows a grey map just like it is failing loading the tiles. Folium tries to download the tiles but it seems that it needs the definition of the proxy. Proxy for QT is defined and works. Is there any possibility to define a proxy server for folium?

**EDIT:**

**Main**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow 
import sys
import io
import folium
import osmnx as ox
from folium.plugins import Draw
import os

from ui_Main import Ui_Main

directory = os.path.realpath(__file__)[:-7]
sys.path.append(directory)

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_Main):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)       
    # self.Load.clicked.connect(self.loadAoI)

   def display_map(self):
       global City
       global Country
       global LatLon
       City = self.lineEdit_city.text()
       Country = self.lineEdit_country.text()
       if City and Country:
           LatLon = ox.geocode(f'{City}, {Country}')
           map_4 = folium.Map(location = LatLon, tiles=None, zoom_start=15, maxZoom = 25, scroll_wheel_zoom = True, control_scale = True)
         folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(tiles='cartodbpositron').add_to(map_4)
           Draw(
            export=True,
            filename='Area_of_interest.geojson',
            position='topleft',
            draw_options={'polyline': False, 'circle': False, 'rectangle': False, 'circlemarker': False},
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}},
        ).add_to(map_4)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        map_4.save(data, close_file=False)            
        self.view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())

   
   def handle_downloadRequested(self, item):
       current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
       filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "Area_of_interest.GEOJSON")

       item.setPath(filename)
       item.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   showMain = Main()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui_Main**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class Ui_Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def setupUi(self, Main):
            Main.setObjectName("Main")
            Main.setFixedSize(1300, 1100)
    
            self.QtStack = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()

            self.stack1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.Window1UI()
            self.QtStack.addWidget(self.stack1)

        def Window1UI(self):
            self.stack1.setFixedSize(1101, 886)
            self.stack1.setWindowTitle('Vehicle Ramming Tool')
    
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.stack1)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.Title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.Title_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 85, 231, 31))
            self.Title_label.setObjectName("Title_label")
            self.Title_label.setText('Do you want to define an Area of Interest?')
    
            self.Title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.Title_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 231, 31))
            self.Title_label.setObjectName("Title_label 1")
            self.Title_label.setText('Choose a location on which perform the analysis:')
    
            self.checkBox_yes = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
            self.checkBox_yes.setEnabled(True)
            self.checkBox_yes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 70, 17))
            self.checkBox_yes.setObjectName("checkBox_yes")
            self.checkBox_yes.setText('Yes')
    
            self.city_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.city_label.setEnabled(True)
            self.city_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 81, 16))
            self.city_label.setObjectName("city_label")
            self.city_label.setText('Enter City Name:')
    
            self.country_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.country_label.setEnabled(True)
            self.country_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 50, 110, 20))
            self.country_label.setObjectName("country_label")
            self.country_label.setText('Enter Country Name:')
    
            self.lineEdit_city = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.lineEdit_city.setEnabled(True)
            self.lineEdit_city.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 113, 20))
            self.lineEdit_city.setObjectName("lineEdit_city")
    
            self.lineEdit_country = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.lineEdit_country.setEnabled(True)
            self.lineEdit_country.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 50, 113, 20))
            self.lineEdit_country.setObjectName("lineEdit_country")
    
            self.Map_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.Map_button.setEnabled(True)
            self.Map_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 80, 40))
            self.Map_button.setObjectName("Map_button")
            self.Map_button.setText('Display Map')
            self.Map_button.clicked.connect(self.display_map)
            self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
            self.view.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(
            self.handle_downloadRequested
            )

            self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 1061, 491))
            self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
            lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
            lay.addWidget(self.view, stretch=1)

    
            self.checkBox_Not = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
            self.checkBox_Not.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 800, 71, 21))
            self.checkBox_Not.setObjectName("checkBox_Not")
            self.checkBox_Not.setText('Not')
    

            self.checkBox_yes.toggled['bool'].connect(self.checkBox_Not.setDisabled)
            self.checkBox_Not.toggled['bool'].connect(self.checkBox_yes.setDisabled)
```

Comment: please  provide  a [mre]

Comment: Thanks, I have added a minimal example.

Comment: please remove useless imports

Comment: It should be fine now, with no useless imports